# Multiplication and division under integral sign for non-constant function: $\int f(t)dt \iff \int f(t)\frac{g(t)}{g(t)}dt$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

Suppose that you have to evaluate an integral

$$\int f(t)dt.$$

Is it allowed to multiply and divide under the integral sign for the same ***non-constant*** function? That is, is it allowed to write: 
$$\int f(t)\frac{g(t)}{g(t)}dt.$$ Why/why not? If yes, under which circumstances?

Comment: g (x)/g (x) is just the number 1.

Comment: Think of it like multiplying by $a/a$. This is okay to do as long as $a\neq0$, that is $g$ is never zero. (Otherwise you divide zero by zero which is a bit of a problem.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can *always* multiply a real muber $f(t)$ by $1$. Therefore it is *always* possible to write
$$
f(t)=f(t)\frac{g(t)}{g(t)},
$$
as long as $g(t) \neq 0$. In particular, the function $g$ should not vanish in the interval where you want to compute your integral.

Comment: Thank you. I thought so, but I wanted to be extra sure.